# JoomLa update query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I'm new to the joomla and php. I having problem on my sql query in joomla in which it does not update the table, and it giving me error message. Is there any mistake i had made on my up date query?

Here is my code:

```
// Get default database object
$db =JFactory::getDBO();

// Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$tmpIds = array();

foreach($courseID as $cId){

$tmpIds[]= $db->quote($cId);
 //sanitize the input

}

$courseID1 = implode(',',$tmpIds);
// Build the query
$query->select($db->quoteName('courseid'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('intake'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('campusid').'='. $db->quote($campusID));

 $query->where($db->quoteName('courseid').'IN('.$courseID1.')');

// Set the query for the DB oject to execute
$db->setQuery($query);
// Get the DB object to load the results as a list of objects
$results = $db->loadObjectList(); 

if($results){

$query = "UPDATE intake SET startdate = $from WHERE courseid = $courseID1 AND campusid = $campusID";
echo"$query";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();



}
else{ echo 'Error';}

}
```

I'm getting this error message.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''TEST2' AND campusid = Campus3' at line 1 SQL=UPDATE intake SET
>   startdate = 05/06/2014 WHERE courseid = 'TEST1','TEST2' AND campusid =
>   Campus3

Where the courseid is an array value that post by other form with a checkbox input.

Comment: What is that error message ?

Comment: use quotes for string data as `SET startdate='". $startdate."'`

Comment: instead of echoing he query please use `echo $query->dump()` and paste in the generated query.  Also if you are starting a new query either empty out the object with `$query->clear()` or give you new query a new name. Also don't forget to execute() the update.

Answer (score 0):

your variable $courseID1 in the query turns out to

```
courseid = 'TEST1','TEST2'
```

while should have been

```
courseid in( 'TEST1','TEST2' )
```

Also your dateformat is wrong for mysql. Try

```
$from=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from));
$query = "UPDATE intake SET startdate = '$from' WHERE courseid in ( $courseID1 ) 
AND campusid = $campusID";
```